# Is a forest a tuple, a set or both?

Tags: graph-theory

Given 3 tree graphs $T_1=(V_1, E_1)$, $T_2=(V_2, E_2)$ and $T_3=(V_3, E_3)$, a forest $F$ can be defined in terms of $T_1,T_2,T_3$ as:

- a set $F=\{T_1,T_2,T_3\}$  or,
- a tuple $F=(V_4,E_4)$ where $V_4 \subseteq (V_1 \cup V_2 \cup V_3)$ and $E_4 \subseteq (E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3)$.

Is defining a forest in any of the above ways correct?

Comment: Are your graphs trees? Forests are disjoint union of trees.

Comment: Yes, they are graphs trees. So, can we say that the forest $F$ is the disjoint union of $T_1,T_2,T_3$ (i.e., $F=T_1 \cup T_2 \cup T_3$) and the result of the disjoint union operation is another graph (i.e., a tuple)? In other words, $F=(V_1 \cup V_2 \cup V_3, E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3)$

Comment: Yes, you can say that. To specify the disjoint nature of this union one usually writes as a square cup i.e., t $\sqcup$

Answer (score 0):

Wiki: "A forest is an undirected graph in which any two vertices are connected by at most one path"

The important thing is that this forbids cycles. Now, assume V1=V2={A,B,C} and V3={}. Furthermore,  let E1={AB,BC} and E2={AC,BC} (E3={}, of course). In both definitions,  you produce the cycle AB, BC, CA, i.e. not a forest. However, note that this depends how exactly you interpret (i) as a graph (this is a bit of an unusual notation... thinking of it,  defining a graph as a set with 3 elements seems weird...I strongly advise against it).